# How and where to place the return statement if data of DatePicker date that selected is empty

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I still new in learning flutter and I currently intend to display text message 'No schedule is available' or animation for the date that user click on the DatePicker widget if there are no schedule that available which retrieve from Firestore Database. How and where should I place the statement?

**Images:**

[image: Date that have schedule]
[image: Date that did not have schedule]

**Code:**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final TaskController controller = Get.put(TaskController());
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  // final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('task');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          addTaskBar(),
          addDateBar(),
          const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          dataRetrieve(),

          // GetData(documentId: db.id),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  GetX<TaskController> dataRetrieve() {
    return GetX<TaskController>(
      init: Get.put<TaskController>(TaskController()),
      builder: (controller) {
        return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: controller.tasks.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print('${controller.tasks[index].note} +1');
                  final _task = controller.tasks[index];
                  if (_task.repeat == 'Daily' ||
                      _task.date == DateFormat.yMd().format(selectedDate) ||
                      _task.repeat == 'Weekly' &&
                          selectedDate
                                      .difference(
                                          DateFormat.yMd().parse(_task.date!))
                                      .inDays %
                                  7 ==
                              0 ||
                      _task.repeat == 'Monthly' &&
                          DateFormat.yMd().parse(_task.date!).day ==
                              selectedDate.day) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 20,
                        vertical: 10,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: _getBGClr(_task.color!),
                        // const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 230, 230),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    _task.title!,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white)),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                                  Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      const Icon(
                                        Icons.access_alarm_rounded,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        size: 18,
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(width: 2),
                                      Text(
                                        '${_task.startTime!} - ${_task.endTime!}',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white)),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                                  Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        _task.note!,
                                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                          textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => UpdatingTaskPage(
                                      id: _task.id!,
                                      title: _task.title!,
                                      note: _task.note!,
                                      isCompleted: false,
                                      date: _task.date!,
                                      startTime: _task.startTime!,
                                      endTime: _task.endTime!,
                                      color: _task.color!,
                                      remind: _task.remind!,
                                      repeat: _task.repeat!,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                                print(_task);
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit_note),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                FirestoreDB.deleteTask(_task.id!);
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.delete,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                } 
                ));
      },
    );
  }
```